# How to dynamically Load the names of files in different folders to Azure SQl DB

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

I need to create an ADF Pipeline. I have 6 different folders in my Blob storage and each folder contains 20 files. I need load all the names of this file along with some other pipeline parameters  into a azure SQl DB table using stored procedure. The name of Files starts with Letter Q. How can we achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the list of files using Get Metadata activity and pass each file name to stored procedure activity by looping through ForEach activity.

Source folders:

[image]

Files in folders:

[image]  [image]

ADF pipeline:

1. Get the list of files from `Get Metadata` activity. Create a dataset with folder and filename parameters and pass values from `Get Metadata` activity as below.
2. If you provide Q* in the file name you will get all the files that start with Q.

[image]

Get Metadata output:

[image]

3. Pass the child items to ForEach activity.

`@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems`

[image]

4. Add Stored procedure activity inside ForEach activity and pass the current item name to the stored procedure parameter. You can add more parameters and pass pipeline parameters to the stored procedure.

[image]

Comment: In this if i need to store the folder name also in Database ,How we can get the folder name

Comment: To get the folder name, in your Get metadata, include only the folder path parameter and get the child items. This will get the folder. Then pass the output to ForEach activity and include another Get Metadata inside ForEach and pass the folder parameter value as current item to get the files.

Comment: NiharikaMoola-MT
Thanks Niharika for your input. If i use the wild card (*) for Folders path in the foreach loop we are not getting the actual folder names. To get the folder name list  first i need to  have a meta activity to look into parent folder and get all the folders and then pass this again to a  for each loop in child pipeline to iterate through all the files. Please let me know if my understanding is correct.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.